# CSS Issue, input[id]+label, :hover, and :checked issue

Tags: css, checkbox, background

So I am having a bit of trouble understanding why this isn't working.
I am trying to replace checkboxes for categories on a sample site i am working on. I am trying to make it do the following:
Appear one way when unchecked,
Appear another way when hovered(checked or unchecked)
Appear a third way when checked(and not hovered).

Is this possible? Here is my html snipped for the section affected

```
                 <input type="checkbox" id="chkGeneral"><label for = "chkGeneral" title = "General"></label>
```

and here is the css where i am attempting to

```
input[type=checkbox]{
   display:none;
}

label {
      /* clickable area */
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0.75em;
    display: inline-block;
}
input[id=chkGeneral] + label{
    background: url('http://velvetcookierecords.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/fb-icon-150px-x-150px.png');
    background-size:100%;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
input[id=chkGeneral]:hover + label{
    background: url('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/sonsofanarchy/images/d/d3/IOS_Icon_150px.png/revision/latest?cb=20130903223258');
    background-size:100%;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
input[id=chkGeneral]:checked + label {
    background: url('http://re-vision.com/webwork/p09image-size-tags/ape-silverback.jpg');
    background-size:100%;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

And here is a jsfiddle showing my problem (I used three images off of google since my files are stored on a database). It should be facebook when unchecked,IOS icon when hovered, and a gorilla when checked.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cdhvbg2t/#&togetherjs=JGlvDqekaw

Thanks for the help, I'm pretty lost with where the mistake is.

Comment: Why do people try to do attribute selectors for ID x) ! You can just use the CSS ID selector : `input#chkGeneral`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `:hover` on your label.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  /* clickable area */
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0.75em;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[id=chkGeneral]+label {
  background: url('http://velvetcookierecords.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/fb-icon-150px-x-150px.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

input[id=chkGeneral]+label:hover {
  background: url('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/sonsofanarchy/images/d/d3/IOS_Icon_150px.png/revision/latest?cb=20130903223258');
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

input[id=chkGeneral]:checked+label {
  background: url('http://re-vision.com/webwork/p09image-size-tags/ape-silverback.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkGeneral">
<label for="chkGeneral" title="General"></label>
```

---

And if it should respond on hover, checked or not, the hover rule need to be last

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  /* clickable area */
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0.75em;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[id=chkGeneral]+label {
  background: url('http://velvetcookierecords.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/fb-icon-150px-x-150px.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

input[id=chkGeneral]:checked+label {
  background: url('http://re-vision.com/webwork/p09image-size-tags/ape-silverback.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

input[id=chkGeneral]+label:hover {
  background: url('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/sonsofanarchy/images/d/d3/IOS_Icon_150px.png/revision/latest?cb=20130903223258');
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkGeneral">
<label for="chkGeneral" title="General"></label>
```

Comment: Thank you, i knew i was going over something simple. I appreciate the quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `#` selector on all of them. Your hover needs to trigger on the `label`. Then if you always want `:hover` to fire, regardless of whether it's checked or not, make the `:hover` selector last.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  /* clickable area */
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0.75em;
  display: inline-block;
}

input#chkGeneral + label {
  background: url('http://velvetcookierecords.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/fb-icon-150px-x-150px.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

input#chkGeneral:checked + label {
  background: url('http://re-vision.com/webwork/p09image-size-tags/ape-silverback.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

input#chkGeneral + label:hover {
  background: url('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/sonsofanarchy/images/d/d3/IOS_Icon_150px.png/revision/latest?cb=20130903223258');
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkGeneral">
  <label for="chkGeneral" title="General"></label>
</body>
```